# Формат даты свойства инфоблока Слайдер

Tags: php, html, битрикс, дата, datetime

Есть свойство инфоблока Слайдер DateTime типа дата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как преобразовать в битриксе значение $arItem["PROPERTIES"]["DateTime"]["VALUE"] в формат вида как на скриншоте снизу (Jan 22, 2020)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу код шаблона слайдера template.php

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>

  <?php
use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;
?>

    <?php
Asset::getInstance()->addCss('C:/OpenServer/domains/bxsite3.ru/local/templates/blog/assets/css/style-starter.css');
Asset::getInstance()->addCss('C:/OpenServer/domains/bxsite3.ru/local/templates/blog/owl/owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css');
Asset::getInstance()->addCss('C:/OpenServer/domains/bxsite3.ru/local/templates/blog/owl/owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css');
Asset::getInstance()->addJs('C:/OpenServer/domains/bxsite3.ru/local/templates/blog/assets/jq/jquery-3.6.0.min.js');
Asset::getInstance()->addJs('C:/OpenServer/domains/bxsite3.ru/local/templates/blog/owl/owlcarousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js');
Asset::getInstance()->addJs('scriptslider.js');
?>


    <!--<section class="w3l-main-slider position-relative" id="home">
    <div class="companies20-content">-->
    <div class="news-list owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <? $i=0; ?>
        <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
          <!--<?echo '<pre>'.print_r($arItem).'</pre>' ?>-->
          <!--<?=$arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PictureUrl"]["VALUE"]; ?>-->
          <? if ($i==0) :?>
            <?
                $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
                $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" =>GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
                ?>
              <div class="item" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
                <div class="slider-info banner-view bg bg2">
                  <div class="banner-info">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="banner-info-bg text-center">
                        <a href="#blog-single.html" class="blog_post_title">
                          <?=$arItem["NAME"] ?>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="author-date mb-4 d-flex align-items-center mt-4 justify-content-center">
                          <!--<?=$arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PictureUrl"]["VALUE"]; ?>-->
                          <li class="circle avatar"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.$arItem[" PROPERTIES "]["PictureUrl "]["VALUE "] ?>" alt=""></li>
                          <li>by <a href="#author.html">Daniel Roberto</a></li>
                          <li><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Jan 22, 2020</li>
                        </ul>

                        <!--<img src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>" />-->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <? $i=$i+1; ?>
                <?else : ?>
                  <div class="item" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
                    <div class="slider-info  banner-view banner-top<?echo $i;?> bg bg2">
                      <div class="banner-info">
                        <div class="container">
                          <div class="banner-info-bg text-center">
                            <a href="#blog-single.html" class="blog_post_title">
                              <?=$arItem["NAME"] ?>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="author-date mb-4 d-flex align-items-center mt-4 justify-content-center">
                              <!--<?=$arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PictureUrl"]["VALUE"]; ?>-->
                              <li class="circle avatar"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.$arItem[" PROPERTIES "]["PictureUrl "]["VALUE "] ?>" alt=""></li>
                              <li>by <a href="#author.html">Daniel Roberto</a></li>
                              <li><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Jan 22, 2020</li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <? $i=$i+1; ?>
                    <?endif; ?>
                      <?endforeach;?>
    </div>
    <!--    </div>
</section>-->
    <!--
<section class="w3l-main-slider position-relative" id="home">
    <div class="companies20-content">
        <div class="owl-one owl-carousel owl-theme">
1
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
-->

    <!--<script src="scriptslider.js"></script>-->
```

и код страницы index.php

```html
<section class="w3l-main-slider position-relative" id="home">
<div class="companies20-content">

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list", 
    "myowlslider", 
    array(
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "f j, Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "FILTER_NAME" => "",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "3",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "slider",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "3",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
        "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
        "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SORT_BY1" => "",
        "SORT_BY2" => "",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "myowlslider"
    ),
    false
);?>

</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если для английского языка, то

```
date('M j, Y', MakeTimestamp($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["DateTime"]["VALUE"]));
```